# Is it possible to infer the date of receiving from the date of sending

Tags: meaning

I received a message from bandcamp informing me that the record was sent on 30 th april

Is my sentence correct ? Can we infer that the message was received around 30th april

Comment: Your name is Yves, if you are a French speaker, note that in English we do not write spaces before question and exclamation marks, like you do in French.

Answer (score 3):

> Is my sentence correct ?

Yes.  You should capitalize *April,* however, and there should not be a space in *30th* (nor should there be a space before the question mark in the question quoted above).

> Can we infer that the message was received around 30th april

There is no basis for that inference.  In fact, the contrary is a real possibility.  For example, you might have waited patiently until November for the record before asking about it, in which case the message might have been received in November.

Again, *April* should be capitalized, and in this case you have omitted the question mark altogether.

Comment: i should write  i received on 1st May a message informing me that the record was sent on 30th April or I received a message on 1st May informing me that the record had just been sent

Comment: ...or you received a message on 1st May informing you that the record had been sent the previous day.